# Pass new line to description field in ics export from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, icalendar, sharepoint-designer

I am exporting an ics file from a sharepoint list item using the following format:

`http://sharepoint/site/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=[List GUID]&CacheControl=1&ID=[Item ID]&Using=event.ics`

I have a column in my list called description, this gets passed to the generated ics file in the correct place but any `\n`'s seem to get escaped to this `\\n` which displays as text in the calendar appointment.

I have tried many different options but cannot seem to get this working.

`\n` gets replaced with `\\n`

`\134n` gets replaced with `\\n`

`\\n` generates correctly but does not work

`\012` seems to break the ics file unless it is followed by a whitespace character, but then it gets unfolded and ignored.

I refuse to believe that this is impossible. Any help will be appreciated and any solution will save me days of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how the original data is stored but icalendar spec (`RFC5545`) specs:

> The "TEXT" property values may also contain special characters
>         that are used to signify delimiters, such as a COMMA character for
>         lists of values or a SEMICOLON character for structured values.
>         In order to support the inclusion of these special characters in
>         "TEXT" property values, they MUST be escaped with a BACKSLASH
>         character.  A BACKSLASH character in a "TEXT" property value MUST
>         be escaped with another BACKSLASH character.  A COMMA character in
>         a "TEXT" property value MUST be escaped with a BACKSLASH
>         character.  A SEMICOLON character in a "TEXT" property value MUST
>         be escaped with a BACKSLASH character.  However, a COLON character
>         in a "TEXT" property value SHALL NOT be escaped with a BACKSLASH
>         character.

Example:  A multiple line value of:

```
   Project XYZ Final Review
   Conference Room - 3B
   Come Prepared.

  would be represented as:

   Project XYZ Final Review\nConference Room - 3B\nCome Prepared.
```

So for your export to work you should leave \n as is, replace CRLF by \n and also hope your user has a standard compliant calendar tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what is required for the ics file to produce a newline character, my issue is that sharepoint seems to be overriding any attempt that I make to send "\n" to the ics output.